# If A is invertible, then it can be represented as a product of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone jog my intuition as to why this is true:

> If A is nonsingular (a matrix exists that if multiplied by A, gives you the identity matrix), then, by Theorem 2.14, it can be written as the product $A = E_k ... E_2E_1$

And Theoreum 2.14 is this:

[image]

Comment: Row operations correspond to multiplication by elementary matrices. This is the Lay text, no?

Comment: Think about row operations, which leads to $I_n$.

Comment: Can one of you guys show me an example? I'll give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if you can row reduce $A$ to an identity matrix $I$. Now each row operation that you use to reduce $A$ to $I$ can be represented by an elementary matrix, which is denoted by $E$. Suppose you need $n$ row operations in order to reduce $A$ to $I$. That means that $$(E_nE_{n-1} \ldots E_1)A=I.$$ Now you probably know that the inverse of a matrix is unique if it exists. So the product $(E_nE_{n-1} \ldots E_1)$ MUST be the inverse of $A$ because the uniqueness of inverse means that there is only one matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}A=I$ holds. Thus, we know $$(E_nE_{n-1}\ldots E_1)=A^{-1}.$$

To write $A$ as the product of elementary matrices, note that $$A=(A^{-1})^{-1}=(E_nE_{n-1} \ldots E_1)^{-1}=E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}\ldots E_n^{-1}.$$

The inverse of an elementary matrix is also an elementary matrix. So the last equation shows $A$ as the product of $n$ elementary metrics.

Comment: oh I see.... the heart of this is that the inverse matrix $A^-$ is unique and represents a series of row reductions.

Comment: The theorem just isn't intuitive to me without your explanation here. Thanks. The first part of the theorem would be more intuitive to me if it said: "A is invertible if its inverse can be written as a series of elementary matrices"...which I now know is equivalent to the original theorem.

Comment: @Jwan622 Do you mean "If $A$ is invertible, then its inverse can be written as the product of elementary matrices"? Your sentence "A is invertible if its inverse can be written as a series of elementary matrices" does not make sense because you cannot speak of the inverse of $A$ before knowing $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give a more detailed proof of this. First, let's recap the following:

**Lemma:** Let $A\in\mathbb{F}^{(m,n)}$. For any of the three elementary row operations on matrices

1. $r_i\mapsto r_j$, $r_j\mapsto r_i$ (swap)
2. $r_i\mapsto \lambda r_i$, $\lambda\neq 0$ (scale)
3. $r_i\mapsto r_i+\lambda r_j$, $j\neq i$ (addition, with scale)

there exists a regular matrix s.t. $C\in\mathbb{F}^{(m,m)}$ s.t. $CA$ is the matrix after the transformation and this matrix is elementary.

**Proof:** I divide between the different types of transformations I've listed. Let

1. *Exchanging row $i$ with row $j$.* Let $$C=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\\vdots\\u_m\end{pmatrix}$$ for row vectors $u_k\in\mathbb{F}^m$ where $u_k=e_k$ for $k\neq i,j$, $u_j=e_i$, $u_i=e_j$. Now, $(CA)_{kl}=\langle u_k,a_l\rangle =\langle e_k,a_l\rangle=A_{kl}$ for $k\neq i$. For $k=i$, $(CA)_{il}=\langle e_j,a_l\rangle=A_{jl}$ and for $k=j$, $(CA)_{jl}=\langle e_i,a_l\rangle=A_{il}$. Thus, $CA$ is $A$ with row $i$ and $j$ swapped. Note, that $C$ itself was created from $E_m$ by swapping row $i$ and $j$, i.e. is elementary. Also, $\det C=-1$, as swapping two rows swaps the sign of the determinant, as the determinant is an alternating function. Thus $C$ is regular as well.
2. *Scaling row $i$ by $\lambda\neq 0$.* Let $C$ be as above with $u_k=e_k$ for $k\neq i$ and $u_k=\lambda e_k$ for $k=i$. Now, it is clear that $C$ is again elementary and that its determinant is $\lambda\neq 0$. For verifying the effect, we look again at $$(CA)_{kl}=\langle u_k,a_l\rangle=\begin{cases}\langle e_k,a_l\rangle=A_{kl} &k\neq i\\\langle\lambda e_k,a_l\rangle=\lambda\langle e_k,a_l\rangle=\lambda A_{kl} &k=i\end{cases}$$
3. *Adding $\lambda r_j$ to $r_i$, $i\neq j$.* Look at the same $C$ with $u_k=e_k$ for $k\neq i$ and $u_k=e_i+\lambda e_j$ for $k=j$. Again, that $C$ is elementary is obvious. You may verify the other properties. They again go in a similar fashion as before.

$\Box$

Now, let $A\in\mathbb{F}^{(n,n,)}$ for some field $\mathbb{F}$ be invertible. I'll use without a concrete proof that $A$ may be transformed into $E_n$ using Gauss-Jordan(elementary row transformation). You can find a sketch in the hint at the end of the post.

As said before, there is a sequence of row transformations $(t_1,\dots, t_k)$ which applied to $A$(sequentially) yield $E_n$. From the before Lemma, we know that every such row transformation corresponds to an elementary matrix $C_k$ and we may write the result as $C_k\dots C_1A=E_n$. (note the direction here, as $t_1$ is applied first to $A$, then $t_2$ to this result and so on) Now, $$C_k\dots C_1A=E_n\text{ implies }C_k\dots C_1=A^{-1}$$ as the inverse is unique. Thus, as $A=(A^{-1})^{-1}$, we have that

$$A=(C_k\dots C_1)^{-1}=C^{-1}_1\dots C^{-1}_k$$

Now, all the $C^{-1}_i$ are invertible again and also elementary. Note also, that I've used without proof, that for a product of matrices $AB$, we have $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

---

Note, that the proof mimics the way you would actually use Gauss-Jordan to compute the inverse. You can look a the block matrix $B=(A,E_n)$ and consider the row transformations $C_1,\dots, C_k$(now directly in matrix form), turning $A$ into $E_n$ applied to $B$. Then $B'=(E_n,C_k\dots C_1E_n)$. As above, $C_k\dots C_1=A^{-1}$, so this tells us also, that $A^{-1}$ may be obtained by applying Gauss-Jordan onto $B$ as long till $A$ was transformed into $E_n$. The right half of $B'$ then shows the inverse of $A$.

---

**Hint:** Now, as $\mathrm{ker}(A)=\{\mathbf0\}$, we have that, by solving $Ax=\mathbf0$ using Gauss-Jordan, that the only solution obtained is $x=\mathbf0$. You may check that this corresponds with $A$ being transformable into upper triangle form using elementary row transformations. From upper triangle form, you can now work up backwards and transform $A$ to $E_n$.