# Prove following 4 equivalence statements about $n$ by $n$ invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Sorry, the title is not as descriptive as I wanted it to be. The theorem is too long for me to write it all out. If you can make it clearer, feel free to edit the title.

---

I would like to prove following theorem

> **Theorem (1.35)**. Let $\mathbf A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix, then the 4 following statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) The matrix $\bf A$ is invertible (non-singular)
>
> (b) The linear system $\bf Ax = O$ only has the trivial solution $\bf x = O$
>
> (c) The reduced row echelon form of the matrix $\bf A$ is the identity
>   matrix $\bf I$
>
> (d) $\bf A$ is a product of elementary matrices

My attempt:

$(a) \implies (b)$:

Suppose $\bf A$ is invertible, then we have
$$\bf A^{-1}Ax = A^{-1}O$$
$$\bf x = O$$

We've shown that $(a) \implies (b)$

$(b) \implies (c)$:

Since $\bf Ax = O$ has a unique solution, it follows that reduced echelon form of matrix $\bf A$ doesn't have row of zeros. And we've [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345158/prove-that-the-reduced-row-echelon-form-rref-of-an-n-by-n-matrix-either-is) that if rref of $n$ by $n$ matrix doesn't have row of zeros, then it will be the identity matrix. Therefore, $(b) \implies (c)$.

$(c) \implies (d)$:

Here I will use the definition of the row equivalence from the same book where the theorem was introduced:

> A matrix $\bf B$ is row equivalent to a matrix $\bf A$ iff there are a finite number of elementary matrices $\bf  E_{1},E_{2},E_{3}.....E_{n}$ such that $\mathbf B = \bf E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n}A$

Now, if $\bf I$ is a rref of $\bf A$, then we can say that $\bf I$ is row equivalent to a $\bf A$, which implies:
$$\bf A = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n}I = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n} $$

From this we can see that, indeed, $\bf A$ is the product of elementary matrices. Hence $(c) \implies (d)$

$(d) \implies (a)$:

The theorem that we need to know there is:

> An elementary matrix is invertible (non-singular) and its inverse is
>   also an elementary matrix.

We have 
$$\bf A = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n} $$

Postmultiply both sides by $E_{n}^{-1}$

$$\bf AE_{n}^{-1} = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n-1}E_{n}E_{n}^{-1} \implies$$
$$\bf AE_{n}^{-1} = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n-1}I$$

Repeat the step with $E_{n-1}^{-1}$:
$$\bf AE_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1} = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n-1}E_{n-1}^{-1} \implies$$
$$\bf AE_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1} = E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....I \implies$$

It can be seen that by repeating same process $n-2$ times, we will end up with:
$$\bf A\bigl(E_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_{3}^{-1}E_{2}^{-1}E_{1}^{-1}\bigr) = I \implies$$
From that it can be seen that $\bf \bigl(E_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_{3}^{-1}E_{2}^{-1}E_{1}^{-1}\bigr)$ is the right inverse of $\bf A$.

To show that $\bf \bigl(E_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_{3}^{-1}E_{2}^{-1}E_{1}^{-1}\bigr)$ is also, in fact, a left inverse A, repeat the same steps above but now using premultiplication:

$$\bf E_{1}^{-1}A = E_{1}^{-1}E_{1}E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n-1}E_{n} \implies$$
$$\bf E_{1}^{-1}A = E_{2}E_{3}.....E_{n-1}E_{n} \implies$$

Repeat steps $n-1$ times, and you will end up with:

$\bf \bigl(E_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_{3}^{-1}E_{2}^{-1}E_{1}^{-1}\bigr) A =  I$

Therefore, $\bf \bigl(E_{n}^{-1}E_{n-1}^{-1}...E_{3}^{-1}E_{2}^{-1}E_{1}^{-1}\bigr) = A^{-1}$, and hence we can conclude that matrix $\bf A$ is invertible. $(d) \implies (a)$

$\Box$

Is it correct? Suggestions to make it clearer/more accurate are welcome!

Comment: See whether this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876348/if-a-is-invertible-then-it-can-be-represented-as-a-product-of-elementary-matric/2876479) helps you.

Comment: Can’t you simply use the general fact that the product of invertible matrices is also invertible?

Comment: @amd Yeah, I could, I've realized it a little late